# Android ObjectAnimator inside custom view

Tags: android, animation, view, invalidation

I have a custom view kind of like a progress bar. inside this view i have an ObjectAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener which i'm trying to use to call invalidate on the view. However, my view is not updating! I tried to add a button which simply changed the value to something else and called invalidate once and it worked, my view updated to reflect the value change.

Am I missing something here? Am I calling invalidate too many times or something?

My "progressbar" starts with a float at 0, and the animation is supposed to animate it to 100. Calling a method to update it to 50 and call invalidate works, but the ObjectAnimator doesnt seem to be calling invalidate.

Everything is being called on the UI Thread

Answer (score 5):

ObjectAnimator does not call invalidate() - your method should do it when needed

```
ObjectAnimator oAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(view,"someproperty",0,100)

void setSomeProperty(value) {
    mValue = value
    invalidate()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have used this and it worked.

```
public interface ProgressAnimationListener {
    public void onAnimationStart();

    public void onAnimationFinish();

    public void onAnimationProgress(int progress);
}

private ObjectAnimator progressBarAnimator;

  public synchronized void animateProgressTo(final int start, final int end, final int duration, final ProgressAnimationListener listener) {

        stopAnimation();
        setProgress(start);

        progressBarAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "animateProgress", start, end);
        progressBarAnimator.setDuration(duration);

        progressBarAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

        progressBarAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(final Animator animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(final Animator animation) {
                setProgress(end);
                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.onAnimationFinish();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(final Animator animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(final Animator animation) {
                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.onAnimationStart();
                }
            }
        });

        progressBarAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(final ValueAnimator animation) {
                int progress = ((Float) animation.getAnimatedValue()).intValue();
                if (progress != getProgress()) {
                    //Log.d(TAG, progress + "");
                    setProgress(progress);
                    if (listener != null) {
                        listener.onAnimationProgress(progress);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        progressBarAnimator.start();
    }

    public synchronized boolean isAnimationRunning() {
        return progressBarAnimator != null && progressBarAnimator.isRunning();
    }

    public synchronized void stopAnimation() {
        if (isAnimationRunning()) {
            progressBarAnimator.cancel();
            progressBarAnimator = null;
        }
    }
```